# Python matching the input with a xml attribute

Tags: python, xml, input, match

I have a XML and a code. But I can't figure out how to do the part.

XML:

```
<settings>
<plugin id="1" name="Send Mail" execute="func/sendmail.py">
    <param name="towhere" value="To Where?" />
    <param name="mailsub" value="Mail Subject" />
    <param name="mailcont" value="Mail Content" />
    <param name="senderid" value="xxxx@gmail.com" />
    <param name="senderpw" value="xxxx" />
</plugin>
<plugin id="2" name="Open Tar" execute="func/taropen.py">
    <param name="tarname" value="Tar file name" />
    <param name="tarloc" value="Tar location" />
    <param name="tardest" value="Tar destination" />
</plugin>
<plugin id="3" name="Server Reboot" execute="func/reboot.py">
    <param name="rebootafter" value="1" />
</plugin>
</settings>
```

Code:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
yXML = minidom.parse('data/config.xml')

for plugin in yXML.getElementsByTagName('plugin'):
    print plugin.getAttribute('id')+"- "+plugin.getAttribute('name')

selection = raw_input("Enter your choice: ")
selection = plugin.getAttribute('id')
if selection:
    import os
    exe = plugin.getAttribute('execute')
    os.system('python '+exe)
```

When I type 1 or 2 as Input, It opens number 3. Could you help?

Output:

```
ubuntu:~/Desktop$ python test.py
1- Send Mail
2- Open Tar
3- Server Reboot
Enter your choice: 1
python: can't open file 'func/reboot.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
ubuntu:~/Desktop$
```

It's too easy to solve but I can not think very well.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use BeautifulSoup for Python, it can parse both HTML and XML. You can specify text to search for by specifiying `text="text"` when parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `for` loop that prints the values is over, `plugin` equals the third object (whose `id` is `3`). So every use of `plugin` after that point will always refer to the server reboot option. Instead, you need:

```
[...]
selection = raw_input("Enter your choice: ")
plugin = yXML.getElementsByTagName('plugin')[int(selection)]
if selection:
  [...]
```

Comment: What might be cleaner is looping over the elements as is already done in the question, and then checking the value of the `id` attribute. That way, when the items are in a different order, you still would get the correct entry.

Comment: ubuntu:~/Desktop python test.py
    1- Send Mail
    2- Tar Open
    3- Server Reboot
    Enter your choice: 2
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    plugin = yXML.getElementsByTagName('plugin')[selection]
    TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
    ubuntu:~/Desktop$

is the new output.

Comment: Okay, so `selection` is a string. You'll have to make it an `int` then. Answer updated.

Comment: selection = raw_input("Enter your choice: ")
plugin = yXML.getElementsByTagName('plugin')[int(selection)-1]
if selection:

That worked flawless for me. You are the beast! Thank you.